# Search All items from select box in php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have form and php file, and I need to query color in array data from database.

data looks like

```
red,white         mustang  1977
black,blue        ford     2000
white,pink,blue   opel     2003
```

and form looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="select.php">

    <p><input type="radio" value="just" checked name="selection">just selected<input type="radio" name="selection" value="allinclude">all include </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="ON">red</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="ON">blue</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="ON">black</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="ON">white</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="ON">pink</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

and I need 2 sql query, one of check all selected options together in data, and one of any of them in data

in my select.php

```
$selection= $_POST["selection"];
$color=implode(",",$_POST["color"]); 

$sql= mysql_query("select model,year,color where color like '%".$color."%'");
```

When I select blue and white, sql returns no row.
If I select white, then returns 2 row

But I want to select all include radio box and select blue and white then return 3 rows

How can I write second sql for all included selection?

Here is new codes, but this is only query latest item in array, not all selected for 'just' section of selection form

```
$selection= $_POST["selection"];
$color=implode(",",$_POST["color"]); 

if($selection=='just'){


$colorselect = explode(',', $color);

foreach($colorselect as $b)

{

$mycolor = trim($b);

$sql= mysql_query("select model,year,color where color like '%".$mycolor."%'");
}

}
else{

$sql= mysql_query("select model,year,color where color like '%".$color."%'");
}
```

Comment: Change all your (color-related) checkbox names to `color[]` then the value to be the color itself. Instead of `value="ON"` do `value="red"` and so on.

Comment: Does your color column have data like `blue,red,white`?  If so that is a horrible design.

Comment: I did it but there is no change in sql

Comment: You will need an array but it is more complicated if you have a comma seperated list in your DB column.

Comment: Why are you using `$malzeme` in `$color= $malzeme=implode(",",$_POST["color"]);`? You should most likely be doing `$color=implode(",",$_POST["color"]);`. Where is `$malzeme` coming from?

Comment: it wrongly written, I fix it

Comment: I think you need to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_find-in-set) instead of `LIKE`. Plus, you're also open to SQL injection, thought I'd mention that.

Comment: nope it is not what I need

Comment: You did change `value="ON">red</p>` to `value="red">red</p>` and the other colors too, right? If you didn't, then that could be the problem why the answers given may not be working for you.

Comment: Please check my latest edit in question

Comment: Your edit still contains `value="ON">` for all your colors plus you're not selecting a table to choose `FROM` as the others have already pointed out. This question does not seem to have any answer possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your first query gets all rows that include *all* of the colors selected - and you need a second query that will get all rows that include *just one or more* of the colors selected. In that case, you need your query to include a series of `OR`s that will check for each individual color in each row. (Note: your query seems to be missing a FROM statement. I have added this in, assuming your table is called `cars`).

Assuming `$colors` is an array of selected colors, eg: `['blue', 'white', 'red']`, you could set up your query as follows:

```
$query = 'SELECT model,year,color FROM cars WHERE ';
$or = '';
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $query .= $or . "color LIKE '%" . $color . "%'";
    $or = ' OR ';
}
```

This will effectively build a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT model,year,color 
FROM cars
WHERE color LIKE '%blue%'
    OR color LIKE '%white%'
    OR color LIKE '%red%'
```

which will select all the rows from your example data - each row contains at least one of the colors selected. If you wanted to change this logic to get all rows that include *all* of the colors, simply change `OR` to `AND` - this will match rows that have all selected colors, regardless of the order in which they were selected.

**Additional thoughts:**

Storing comma separated values like `blue,white` is usually bad practice. Consider normalizing your data and use a system that includes something like a `colors` and `car_colors` table.

mysql_* functions are deprecated. Consider switching to [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**UPDATE:**

Here is the complete system. This will create the appropriate query based on which radio button is selected:

(Assuming the sample data you provided is in a table called `cars`)

form:

```
<form method="POST" action="select.php">
    <p><input type="radio" value="just" checked name="selection">just selected<input type="radio" name="selection" value="allinclude">all include </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red">red</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue">blue</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black">black</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white">white</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="pink">pink</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

select.php:

```
$selection = $_POST['selection'];
$colors = $_POST['color'];

$op = $selection == 'just' ? ' AND ' : ' OR ';
$query = 'SELECT model,year,color FROM cars WHERE ';
$and_or = '';
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $query .= $and_or . "color LIKE '%" . $color . "%'";
    $and_or = $op;
}

$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: @Seyhan Without more details it's hard to help you. But, I went ahead and wrote out the whole system. See my recent update.

Comment: @Seyhan I see it, but it can't be working at all - you're still missing `FROM`. You're query can't work like that - you have to specify which table you are selecting from. Beyond that, you're logic doesn't seem right. Look at my code under **UPDATE**. That is the answer. You don't need `implode` or `explode` and you don't need to run multiple queries. Use the code from my answer.

Comment: How can I use this script for different multiple select box or radio box forms. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222202/php-mysql-advanced-search-select-box-and-radio-box-issues

Comment: can you please check it out my latest comment?

Answer (score 0):

The effective HTML of Fred -ii-s comment is:

```
<form method="POST" action="select.php">

    <p><input type="radio" value="just" checked name="selection">just selected<input type="radio" name="selection" value="allinclude">all include </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="red">red</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="blue">blue</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="black">black</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="white">white</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="pink">pink</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

And then in your PHP code you would just use the `$_POST['colors']` array of data like any other array in PHP.

```
$colors = implode($_POST['colors'],',');
$sql= mysql_query("select model,year,color where color in (".$colors.")");
```

Comment: Form and select of all selected colors work fine but I need to search each selected color in all arrays

Comment: Is your system setup so that cars can have more than 1 color, or is each car designated as 1 color only? because if so the PHP I gave you should work

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ....

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="select.php">

    <p><input type="radio" value="just" checked name="selection">just selected<input type="radio" name="selection" value="allinclude">all include </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red">red</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue">blue</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black">black</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white">white</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="pink">pink</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

Your PHP:

```
$colors = array("red", "blue", "black", "white", "pink");

// Make sure that only allowed colors make through - we don't want SQL injection
$selection = array();
foreach ($_POST["colors"] as $color)
  {
    if (in_array($color, $colors) === true)
      {
        $selection[] = $color;
      }
  }

// Now a bit of magic
$sql= mysql_query("select model,year,color from data where color like '%" . implode("%' " . ($_POST["selection"] === "just" ? "or" : "and") . " color like '%",$selection) . "%'");
```

Comment: I got array from mysql database, this is not work good for me

Comment: What do you mean by 'I got array from mysql database'? Mysql returns arrays on selects - it is normal :)

Comment: yes, this may work with using same as this but I take my array from database. and it doesn't work

Comment: Would you please be specific: which array do you take from database? And what does not work?

Comment: look at my data entry, colors are in array. I checked different colors from form. if selected color are not in one array, query returns null. but I need to query all arrays in table for each selected color in form

Comment: I have amended my answer to use array of colors returned from the browser. Still not sure about 'all arrays in table for each selected color' but I think you want to replace %' and like '% to %' or like '%

Comment: Ok, but colors array in your script must be taken from form like $color=implode(",",$_POST["color"]); So how can I define $selection ?

Comment: Hmm... Can you see $_POST["colors"] in foreach statement? $selection is defined inside foreach for the purposes of sanitizing of input. Then selection is used in implode.

Comment: I have amended my answer and checked that it works. Please make sure that you have table called 'data' with the data you have shown above.