# php mysql advanced search select box and radio box issues

Tags: php, mysql, advanced-search

I want to add advanced search into my web page

I use this form for getting data

```
<form action="advsearch.php" method="POST" >

Search <input type="text" name="oneword" size="20"> word

<p>Time <input type="radio" value="30" name="time">30 min 
    az <input type="radio" name="time" value="60">60 min
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="120">120 min
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="1000" checked>any</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</p>

Cities 

<?php

while($cities=mysql_fetch_array($whichcity)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='$cities[cityname]'>$cities[cityname]";
}
?>

    <p>Category

<?php

while($categories=mysql_fetch_array($whichcat)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categories[]' value='$categories[catname]'>$categories[catname]";
}
?>

    </p>
<p>Weather <input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" value="Rainy">Rainy
    <input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" value="Cloudy">Cloudy
    <input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" value="Clear">Clear
    <input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" value="Foggy">Foggy</p>
<p>&nbsp;Person<input type="radio" name="person" value="2">1-2 person<input type="radio" name="person" value="4">3-4 
    person<input type="radio" name="person" value="6">5-6 person<input type="radio" name="person" value="100" checked>any

    </p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>


</form>
```

I got some fields from database, anyway I successfully post form and get data but my search results are wrong

I got data like this

```
$oneword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oneword']); 
$time = (int)$_POST['time'];
$cities= implode(",",$_POST["cities"]);
$categories= implode(",",$_POST["categories"]);
$weather= implode(",",$_POST["weather"]);
$person= (int)$_POST['person'];
```

here is the sql query

```
$sql= mysql_query("select * from mytable where time <= '".$time ."' and person = '".$person."' and  category like '".$categories."' and  cities like '".$cities."' and  weather like '".$weather."' and word like '%".$oneword."%' or description like '%".$oneword."%'    ");
```

So, how can I do advanced search like this?

Comment: this is wrong `$weather= weather(",",$_POST["weather"]);
`

Comment: yes it's my mistake, I fixed it

Comment: You have `name="oneword"` but using with `($_POST['word '])` Plus, that space in `['word ']` will also cause problems.

Comment: You also have a space inside `['time ']` which will also cause you problems.

Comment: While developing, it's always useful to echo $sql;

Comment: My common problem is sql query, don't care mistakes in form

Answer (score 2):

Your query was returning incorrect result because of the final `OR` operator qualified all records with `descriptions` containing `$oneword`. Instead, you need to use `()` to group the text search conditions together.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where time <= '".$time ."' and person = '".$person."' 
  and  category in ('". implode("','", $_POST['categories']) ."') 
  and  cities in ('". implode("','", $_POST['cities']) ."')
  and  weather in ('". implode("','", $_POST["weather"]) ."') 
  and (word like '%".$oneword."%' or description like '%".$oneword."%');
```

Comment: Also, the `LIKE` operator takes a string with wildcards. What you have are comma-separated lists. Use the `IN` function instead, eg. `weather IN (" . $weather . ")"`.

Comment: @NisseEngström, good point. answer's updated per your suggestion.

Comment: but this was no roe returns for every search

Comment: @Seyhan, can you print the query before sending it to `mysql_query`?

Comment: Actually I found different problem, if I do not select any option for select box, then there is no rows return. How can I do search for all if no one selected?

Comment: You can certainly build up the query with a few `if (!empty($_POST['categories'])){$query.=' and categories ...'}` statement. But I think it's more reasonable to make all checkboxes preselected.

Comment: Well but if I multiple select fo categories, then no row returns again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55634/discussion-between-fabricator-and-seyhan).